# Windows System Classes vs Windows Controls

Tags: c++, c, class, controls, system

I'm curious as to what is the difference between:

- Windows created using **Window System Class**, as seen in: [MSDN: Window System Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-window-classes#system-classes)
- **Windows Controls**, as seen in: [MSDN: Windows Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/window-controls)

It seems to me that both serve the same purpose. I'd even dare to say both are the same thing. Creating a window using a **Window System Class** seem to be a little bit more fiddly to work with, in contrast to **Windows Controls** where one can simply drag-n-drop them in a Dialog Box (*and of course add it programmatically*). Is it just a matter of backwards compatibility?

Also in the first link ([MSDN: Window System Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-window-classes#system-classes)), there seems to only exist a handful of **Window System Classes**, compared to the number of **Windows Controls** one can choose from.

As I'm writing this question, and looking for links, I've just found a page talking about this ([MSDN: Control Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/control-messages)), that seems to support my initial thought of this mess being all about backwards compatibility. In there you can read:

> (...) common controls send notifications as either WM_COMMAND or WM_NOTIFY
>   messages, as specified in the reference topic for the notification.
>   **Typically, older notifications (those that have been in the API for a**
>   **long time) use WM_COMMAND**.

I'm curious to know if anyone here ever thought about this, and dug deep down inside Microsoft's crazy and gigantic documentation to find an answer for this.

The quote above might just have answered my own question, but I still post it here in case someone else has a few cents they want to add to this topic.

Thanks

Comment: `The quote above, might just have answered my own question` Yeah, it might :)

Comment: "Windows system classes" come as part of the window manager and require no extra effort to import into your project. All other classes are provided by other DLLs, such as the common controls DLL. Using those other DLLs typically requires an extra step like calling `InitializeCommonControls()` or [loading the required library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/about-rich-edit-controls).

Comment: That makes sense